# .Sh script to install java at a specific location

Tags: shell, ubuntu, sh

I am using following command to install java 8 in my ubuntu 32 bit matchine.I am using .sh file to run these commands-

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default

read -t 10
```

It's working fine but I am facing two problems

- It set default location in environment variable of java(I want to install in my specific direcory like home/abc/ something and set enviornment variable according to that)
- I want to pause script for 10 seconds at the end to check console.

I just want to check either my enviornment variable is set or not I am using this comamnd in my .sh file

```
export PATH=$PATH:$(pwd)/Linux_32/Software/jdk1.8.0_20/bin
```

and when I open terminal and check

```
java -version
```

It does not show me anything that is why I what to check is there anything problem with java installation. but each time .sh terminal get closed

Comment: [Why](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) do you want it to pause at the end? For example, if you want to check that the commands worked, use `set -o errexit`.

Comment: @l0b0 I want to check what error is occured while installation. Currently terminal get closed just after error occured or installation completed that's why I am not able to check errors.

Comment: The terminal shouldn't close when a script fails. Did you by accident add `set -o errexit` to your shell configuration?

Comment: @l0b0 Actually I just want to check either my enviornment variable is set or not I am using this comamnd in my .sh file
    export PATH=$PATH:$(pwd)/Linux_32/Software/jdk1.8.0_20/bin
and when I open terminal and check 
    java -version 
It does not show me anything that is why I what to check is there anything problem with java installation. but each time .sh terminal get closed

Comment: Please include this sort of information in the question. And what is the full output when running `java -version`?

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are trying to run `java -version` after the script but the modified PATH environment variable does not persist beyond the script. They're running in different shells. To validate, run `printenv PATH` and you'll notice the jdk path is not appended.

You could try running `java -version` within the script or add the jdk to your `PATH` after the script runs, e.g. in your `.profile` or `.bashrc`.